# How do I create a number guessing game using javascript and react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So, i need to create a React web app that includes 2 views, one of them being a simple number guessing game. I installed npx on my computer and created a react app that includes all the default files there (app.js, index.js etc.) Yet, i dont have any clue how to code without an html file.

I got bits of codes like this

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link re="stylesheet" href="App.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <p>Guess a number between 1 - 100.</p>
        <p id="outputtext">Enter a number below</p>
        <input type= "text" id="userInput"><button id="btn">Enter</button>
    </div>

    <script src="App.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

````
  background-color: #0E2431;
  border: 5px solid #F5E4C3;
  height: 275px;
  width: 750px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

p{
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#input {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

#btn {
  margin: 25px auto auto 5px;
}```

game.js
``` let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    let output = document.getElementById('outputtext');

    let number = [Math.floor(Math.random()*100)]

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
      let input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
      if (input == number){
        output.innerHTML = 'You guessed right, your number was ${number}'
      } else if (input < number){
        output.innerHTML = "You guessed too low!"
      };
      if (input > number){
        output.innerHTML = "You guessed too high!"
      }
});```

But i don't know how i am able to recreate this in react, as there is no html file. Need help with this!
````

Comment: Hi Ricardos! If you've never approached React before I'd recommend going through the docs before wanting to start any project. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

In ReactJs we use a syntax similar to HTML called JSX. In JSX you have a few differences to HTML, but they are minor.

You have to wrap you jsx code in a parent component (like a div)

In the App.js file, you declare a class which will be the Component:

```
//in App.js
import React from 'react'
import './style.css'
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props) //overrides the default props
        this.state = {
            number: 0,
            output: "Enter a number below",
            input: "",
        }//the so-called state is just all the variables you document needs
    }
    //Here is your game.js logic
    game = () => {
        this.setState({number: Math.floor(Math.random()*100)})
        if (input == number){
        this.setState({output:String('You guessed right, your number was ${number}')})
        } 
        else if (input < number){
        this.setState({output: "You guessed too low!"})
        }
        if (input > number){
            this.setState({output: "You guessed too high!"})
        }
    }
    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                 <p>Guess a number between 1 - 100.</p>
                 <p id="outputtext" value = {this.state.output} name = "output">{this.state.output}</p>
                 <input type= "text" id="userInput" name = "input" onChange = {this.handleChange} value = {this.state.input}>
                 <button id="btn" onClick = {this.game}>Enter</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

As you can see, the build and the logic is all in one place, making it easy to implement logic in your app. You can add the style to a style.css file and import it as I have done. Just give your tags a `className` to access them in css. I hope I could help you. If you have any further questions, just reply :)

As you can see, there is no curly brace needed when refrencing a function in jsx.

Comment: thank you very much, i did that, what's next, what should i do with the game.js? Where do i put that code?

Comment: Okay. I have implemented your logic. Take a look. Any questions? Just let me know.